# symfony routing not take into account in app/config/routing

Tags: symfony, routes

Here my main routing file `(in app/confige/routing.yml)`, and the point is that whatever route I put, it works! I'm a bit lost!

```
sdz_administration:
    resource: "@sdzAdministrationBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}//whatever

sdz_bikind:
    resource: "@sdzBikindBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}//whatever
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr|es

sdz_user:
    resource: "@sdzUserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

I have erased the cache and delete the browsing history. But it did nothing.

Comment: What does `app/console router:debug` say?

Comment: Is there a route in one of your config files which has `pattern:  /`?